# How to say animal feed in Japanese? Is there a particular verb for eating when the subject is an animal?

Tags: meaning, words, usage, word-usage

Is the verb 食【た】べる used for animals that are eating?

Is animal food called 食事【しょくじ】?

I was having a conversation about a cat. I wanted to know what the cat was eating and the conversation came off track. I think that the person I was chatting with thought that I meant that I was eating her cat!

I said

> あなたの猫【ねこ】は何【なに】の食事【しょくじ】を食べますか。

Thank you.

Comment: Btw, 食事 does not mean "food", even for humans. It means _meal_, i.e. the act of eating itself. Food is 食べ物.

Comment: but not for animals :)

Comment: Normally one would ask what a person feeds their pet, not what their pet eats. Otherwise it might be dead birds, snails, grass, etc...  It has been recommended to you to use ALC and other resources, which would have helped you out this time: https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=feed+a+dog https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=feed+a+cat .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you could use [餌]{えさ}.

> あなたの猫はどんな餌を食べますか？

or more simply...

> あなたの猫は何を食べますか？

Comment: Is animal food called esa?

Comment: そうですね.. https://jisho.org/word/%E9%A4%8C

Comment: おしえてくれてどうもありがとう